# React Native tab navigation initialRouteName Change dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using createBottomTabNavigation in react native. I want to change initialRouteName using props.

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution of this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

const PhocasTabScreen= createBottomTabNavigator({
{
  ....
}
{
  abBarPosition:'bottom',
  initialRouteName:{this.props.initialRouteName},
}

)}

export default PhocasTabScreen;

PhocasTabScreen.propsTypes={
  initialRouteName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

then you use somewhere you have to pass initial route name..

```
<PhocasTabScreen
            initialRouteName="Home"
/>
```